# Powershell addscript and invoke from C# not displaying result on command line

Tags: c#, powershell

I've the below powershell script file

C:\user\deskptop\script1.ps1

The contents of the script is just the below:

```
get-process
```

i'm trying to create a C# console app to get the output of this script on console. When i execute the script outside C# it runs fine but when i execute it inside C# it doesn't produce anything. i'm trying use addscript and invoke.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace InvokePowerShellScriptFrmCsharp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string script = @"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\script1.ps1";


            PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create();

            shell.AddScript(script);
            //shell.AddCommand("get-process");

            shell.Invoke();
            //shell.AddScript(script).Invoke();

            Collection<PSObject> pSObjects = shell.Invoke();

            foreach (PSObject p in pSObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When i execute the above i get the console with 'Press any key to continue' but no output before that.

but if i just try the below i get the result

```
shell.addcommand("get-process");
```

I want to get this working with addscript coz in the future if there is more than one command in the powershell script then i need to be able to execute the script from C# for desired results.

i've tried many links to try research but don't seem to be getting it to work.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/692mb1/running_powershell_scripts_in_c/

Could someone please let me know where i could be going wrong.

Comment: Why are you doubling your slashes with a string literal?  That's probably your issue.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 , I tried removing the double slashes with single slash and executed, but still i'm not seeing any output

Comment: I'm assuming you obfuscated your example to not include the username in `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 , yes, that is correct.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code, so we can't diagnose your problem. As noted, don't use `\\ ` to `\ ` inside verbatim strings (`@"..."`), but with filesystem paths that mistake is benign. Also note that `.AddScript()`, despite its name, is not for adding _paths to script files_, but for adding pieces of PowerShell source code - again, that shouldn't make a difference in this case, given that the path string has no embedded quoting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try loading the script contents first, then passing that to the `AddScript` method:

```
string script = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Scripts\script1.ps1");
```

Comment: Thanks! that fixed my issue.

Comment: @user3807741: Glad to hear that solved your problem, but in order to help future readers we need to understand _why_, given that your own attempt (minor problems mentioned in the comments on the question notwithstanding) should have worked too. So: why does this approach make a difference? Was there a problem with your script's character encoding? `File.ReadAllText()` assumes UTF-8, whereas when Windows PowerShell reads a script file it assumes the system's "ANSI" encoding. Is that what accounts for the difference?

Comment: @mkelement0, sorry for the delayed response. i saw your comment only today. i actually used streamreader to read the contents of the file and then pass it to the addscript method. That worked. not sure why addscript doesn't read the contents of the file by itself.